# QTooltip that does not depend on mouse

Tags: c++, qt

I currently am attempting to display a tooltip on focusOutEvent of a widget. This tooltip basically validates the data inside the Widget (QLineEdit). Now the problem is I want to display the errors or issues using a tooltip . Here is what I am doing

```
void MyLineEdit::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *e)
{
  QLineEdit::focusOutEvent(e);
  QToolTip::showText( this->mapToGlobal( QPoint( 0, 0 ) ), "Something got it" );
  emit(focussed(false));
}
```

Now the problem is the QTooltip is not displayed that is probably because the mouse is moving. My question is how can I make QTooltip be displayed and keep it there until I wish to turn it off ??

Comment: Maybe you can write your own "tooltip" class? For example, it could ba a frameless `QLabel` that you can show in desired position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tooltip will only show up if a `QHelpEvent` was intercepted. While you can send one from `focusOutEvent` using `QCoreApplication::PostEvent` and subclass `QWidget::event` like this

```
bool MyLineEdit::event (QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::ToolTip) {
         QHelpEvent *helpEvent = static_cast<QHelpEvent *>(event);
         QToolTip::showText(helpEvent->globalPos(), "Something got it");

         return false;
     }
     return QWidget::event(event);
}
```

, this has two undesirable consequences.

1) The event would still be triggered whenever a tooltip would be shown normally (that is, when your mouse pointer stays on the widget for a couple of seconds). You will have to implement some kind of recognition mechanism to distinguish your own help events from the rest.

2) The tooltip is only active while the respective widget is focused. So, displaying a tooltip when the focus is lost will show it only for a couple of seconds, until the next event loop is processed.

There might be a workaround for the latter, but at this point, it is probably better to leave the tooltips for their intended purpose and implement your own pseudo-tooltip which you would control directly.

Comment: +1: I agree - "it is probably better to leave the tooltips for their intended purpose". There is a point at which the workarounds yield code so convoluted that it trumps any savings from code reuse. Tooltips are quite trivial to implement as a styled label.